# How to use command to insert a space in insert mode?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

As title. Given that I'm already in insert mode and there is some insert mode function. Inside the function, I want to insert a space by command, how?

Comment: if you are inside an insert mode function just returning `' '` does not work (e.g. returning a space)?

Answer (score 0):

something like the following snippet works while in Insert Mode and typing `<C-o>:call Testing()`

```
function! Testing()
  echom 'testing...'
  exec 'normal! i '
  echom 'done.'
endfunction
```

(added it to my `.vimrc` for testing)